# retreive the value from json data format in js

Tags: javascript

output in json format

```js
[{
  "school_id": "248",
  "server_url": "http:\/\/testdummy.brainyknights.in\/AndroidAppv5\/",
  "school_id_string": "jayanagar",
  "logo_path": "0",
  "about": "all"
}]
```

how to  retrieve the value of ***school_id*** in js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are two way

```
let data = [{"school_id":"248","server_url":"http:\/\/testdummy.brainyknights.in\/AndroidAppv5\/","school_id_string":"jayanagar","logo_path":"0","about":"all"}];
```

one:

```
data[0].school_id
```

two

```
data[0]['school_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have first to parse the json:

```
var obj = JSON.parse("...you json string here");
// This will return you the school id of the fisrt entry of your array.
var school_id = obj[0].school_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
let data = [{
  "school_id": "248",
  "server_url": "http:\/\/testdummy.brainyknights.in\/AndroidAppv5\/",
  "school_id_string": "jayanagar",
  "logo_path": "0",
  "about": "all"
}];

console.log(data[0].school_id); // use this if just one object in array
console.log(`-----------------------------------------------`)
data.forEach(o=>console.log(o.school_id)); // use this if more than one objects in array
```

If you have one object in your array then you can target it's `[0]`th index to get the desired property of target object. Otherwise you have to loop through each object if there are multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the schoolid from your JSON

```js
var t = JSON.parse('{"school_id": "248", "server_url": "http:\/\/testdummy.brainyknights.in\/AndroidAppv5\/", "school_id_string": "jayanagar", "logo_path": "0", "about": "all"}');
alert(t['school_id'])
```